# Facebook LogIn and Parse

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've just added Facebook login to my app, I can retrieve the data I need. But I'm not completely sure what to do with it. My app already works with normal users to Parse.com (which I registered on a register screen that I have created in my app). But what I want to know is if there is a way to sync Facebook and Parse.com in that I mean to send just the Email, password, username and fullname from the Facebook account to the server or do I need to do it like this: Retrieve Facebook user data > Register the user by putting the data I got into columns on parse.com > Login to MainActivity

Or is there a way to do this: Press Facebook Login Button > Login to MainActivity

Comment: Will do, I'll mess around with it today and see. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse provided an easy way to work with Facebook user [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-facebook-users)

Comment: Are you still here? I need a bit of help.

Comment: Yes, what do you need?

Comment: Oh never mind I got it, I had trouble with permissions, I knew what they were I just didn't know if i could write them in a list. Thanks for the link, it helped me out. :)

Comment: Great. Good luck to you, Ivan!